# Наилучший способ сохранения фотографий

Tags: android, android-room

Каким образом лучше всего получать фотографии от пользователя и сохранять их (или их путь) в базе данных (RoomDataBase)?; Фотографии не требуется обрабатывать и они нужны только для отображения их внутри приложения

Comment: лучше путь сохранить в бд, и потом просто вытаскивать его по id например или по запросу к бд, путь будет к папке приложения